# Why Object#hashCode() returns int instead of long

Tags: java

why not:

```
public native long hashCode();
```

instead of:

```
public native int hashCode();
```

for higher chance of achieving unique hash codes?

Comment: This might make more sense with 64-bit JDKs, however even today a long hashCode would make too little difference.  Hashcode don't have to be unique and 32-bit int is fine provided you have significantly less than 4 billion entries.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I agree with you in principle, but [Preshing](http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/) shows that because of the nature of this problem, there is a 50% chance of a collision even when your hash table as as few as 77,163 entries!

Comment: @KedarMhaswade a HashMap with 78K entries is likely to have 128k capacity so only 17 bits of the agitated hashCode are used.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Because the [maximum length of an array](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html#25566) is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Since the prime use of `hashCode()` is to determine which slot to insert an object into in the backing array of a `HashMap`/`Hashtable`, a hashcode > `Integer.MAX_VALUE` would not be able to be stored in the array.

Comment: Valid point. I'm not sure that  it's documented in spec, but `HashMap` from Sun JDK cannot have table bigger than `1 << 30` (~ `Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2`)

Comment: -1: The backing array is almost always much smaller, so it needs to be scaled down anyway. Scaling down from 64 bit would not really be a problem. Besides, hashCode() is allowed return negative values...

Comment: Why don't use long also in arrays?

Comment: @Nikolas we can't use long as an array index, just think, for 1-th index how many sub-indexes you would capable to store, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.1.1.1 and so on; doing so it will make, more overhead than the solution you need!

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, the hash code value will be used to determine a number of row in a table which is relatively small value.

In `HashMap`, for instance, the default table contains <strike>256 rows</strike> only 16 rows (Sun JDK 1.6.0_17). This means that the row number is determined in the way like this:

```
int rowNumber = obj.hashCode() % rowsCount;
```

So, the real distribution is from 0 to `rowsCount`.

**UPD**: I remember the implementation of `ConcurrentHashMap`. In a nutshell, `ConcurrentHashMap` contains many relatively small tables. At first the `hashCode` function is used to determine the table number, and after that the same function is used to determine a row in the selected table.

This approach removes the limitation of array size (and even allows to build distributed hash table).

So, I incline to the conclusion that `hashCode` returns `int` because it covers the vast majority of use cases.

Comment: This isn't quite accurate, as the size of the table can be different than the default value, either as the table grows or if different arguments for `initialCapacity` are passed to the `HashMap` constructor.

Comment: And what is not accurate? :) Nobody argues that the table can have bigger size the default.

Comment: you need to remove the highest bit (now the rowNumber can be negative) `(obj.hashCode &0x7fffffff)%rowCount`. Since mod operation is like 30 cpu clocks (bitwise and is 1), the number of entries is kept a power-of-2 and the operation is just `(obj.hashCode & (array.length-1))`

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume it's a balance of computation cost vs. hash range. Hashcodes are so frequently referenced that pushing around twice as much data every time you need a hash would be expensive, especially if you consider more common use cases -

for example - if you create a small hash with 10, or 100, or 1000 values, the difference in the number of hash collisions you're going to see will be extremely negligible. For larger hashes, ... well, think of how big a hash will need to be for 10**32 values to start having frequent collisions, and whether that's even possible to do in a JVM given the amount of memory you'd need.