# Why was hashcode designed to return int

Tags: java, hashcode

It seems like a hashcode always returns an int. Now this appears to be a limiting factor due to IntMax. Now one can argue that such we would never have so many objects, as it would cause heap overflow etc. But if we chose `double` instead of int then we could guarantee with a much larger extent that hashcode wont be unique for distinct objects ?

Comment: Why `double` and not `long`, if that's your concern? (Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4166195/139010)

Comment: I apologize its a duplicate, i meant to ask why int ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashcodes don't *need* to be unique. That's why they are hashcodes. For use in hashing algorithms. Which don't need unique keys.

Comment: You want them to be unique for objects you consider to be distinct, otherwise good luck using them in hashed collections...

Comment: @Space_Pope No. You want them to be *distinct* for objects that are distinct. It isn't the same thing.

Comment: Fair enough; I meant unique for objects of that type and for the current run of the program, but "distinct" is a much more concise way of saying that :).

Comment: @Space_Pope Again, no. 'Distinct' and 'unique' mean completely different things. One isn't a 'more concise way of saying' the other. You were just misusing the word 'unique'.